# $.when vs Q.when behavior with Deferreds

Tags: jquery, promise, q

I'm working with the Q.js library to do promises.  I've tried the following scenario, where a function waits on another one to resolve a deferred before executing some code, and it works fine with jQuery native promises.  However, the same code returns immediately with Q.js.  Any ideas?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ArN8F/5/

---

HTML:

```
<button id='go'>Go</button>
<p id='txt'></p>
<p id='txt2'></p>
```

jQuery code (waits 2 seconds then changes the text):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $('#go').click(function () {
        $('#txt').text('Clicked!');
        promised();
        setTimeout(dfd.resolve, 2000);
    });

    function promised() {
        $.when(dfd).done(function () {
            $('#txt2').text('Done');
        });
    }
})
```

Q.js code (changes text immediately):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dfd = Q.defer();
    $('#go').click(function () {
        $('#txt').text('Clicked!');
        promised();
        setTimeout(dfd.resolve, 2000);
    });

    function promised() {
        Q.when(dfd, function () {
            $('#txt2').text('Done');
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Maybe it is already resolved unexpectedly? What happens if a *new* deferred is created in the click event? Also, the equivalent to `Q.when(dfd, ..)` in jQuery is `dfd.then(..)`, and *not* `$.when` (which is an aggregator equivalent to `Q.all`).

Comment: No, it's as simple as shown.  I've even used Q.all, which never returns in this case.  Check the fiddle I just added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you should use `Q.when` like this:

```
Q.when(dfd.promise, function () { 
     // .. 
});
```

Notice that it is `dfd.promise`, not just `dfd`.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuxk8/).

Comment: Thanks.  I can't believe it was that.  Pretty lame for Q to require the .promise.

Comment: Agreed, but you can try it to be sure. As for me I like jQuery's deferred objects more.